# Какова должна быть структура проекта в Nuxt.js + сервере и базе данных?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, vue.js, nuxt.js

Всем привет.
Я начинающий разработчик и на данный момент только планирую работать с серверными технологиями.
Сейчас столкнулся с отсутствием знания того как необходимо работать с базой данных и сервером + с nuxt.js(в режиме статического деплоя.)

Вопрос:
Существует ли папка(внутри проекта NUXT.js) в которую с точки зрения проектирования было бы правильно ложить файлы с сервером(node.js, без express.js) + где держать файлы с базой данных?
(Например если это Postgresql)

Если таких папок не предусмотрено - то как поступить наиболее правильно в данном случае?
Где конкретно хранить все эти файлы?
(как до деплоя так и после.)

Если перефразировать и попробовать описать задачу с другого угла то:
я планирую делать статический деплой на Nuxt.js и через axios обмениваться данными с удаленным(или для начала даже у себя на локалке) сервером.
(который будет доставать данные из базы данных и передавать их на клиентскую часть для генерации HTML елементов.)

P.S. Буду благодарен за конструктивные советы..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Существует ли папка(внутри проекта NUXT.js) в которую с точки зрения
>   проектирования было бы правильно ложить файлы с сервером(node.js, без
>   express.js) + где держать файлы с базой данных?

Это описано [тут](https://ru.nuxtjs.org/api) на русском и в большем объеме но на английском [тут](https://nuxtjs.org/api/nuxt).
На счет Postgresql, на сколько знаю она не должна храниться в файлах проекта, а на сервере который работает как процесс.

> через axios обмениваться данными с удаленным(или для начала даже у
>   себя на локалке) сервером

Если был бы ssr(universal вроде правильнее называть), то можно было бы расширить его как описано в двух ссылках выше и использовать как api. Но если Вы решили делать статический деплой, без nodeJS сервереа, то тут надо делать удаленный сервер, но за него конечно надо платить. На счет того что Вы писали что можете доставать данные с локалки, надеюсь вы не будете обращаться к localhost тупо?) Если надо бесплатная бд, то можно использовать [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/), у них есть Cloud Firestore и Realtime Database, для firebase есть еще удобные пакеты. Для API сервера можно использовать [heroku.com](http://heroku.com), там можно создать бесплатные два сайта: один сайт на nodeJS, второй на php.

Comment: >> На счет того что Вы писали что можете доставать данные с локалки, надеюсь вы не будете обращаться к localhost тупо?)
<br />
Честно говоря как то так и планировал )
На счет firebase - когда то думал над этим - но после вот этой статьи как то перехотелось )
https://habr.com/company/everydaytools/blog/329282/

Comment: Это сложная тема чтобы делать сервер на своем компе, по крайнер мере надо платить за статический IP. Надо настраивать роутер, переброс портов, брандмауэр, новичку будет сложно.